# How to fix "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT."

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

When I submit a request to update some data, I get this error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.". How to get rid of this?

Here I've added codes of web.php, AdminController.php and JS function to populate datatable.

**route:**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '/admins'], function () {
    Route::get('/show', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@show',
        'as'   => 'admins.show',
    ]);

    Route::put('/approve/{id}',     [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@approve',
        'as'   => 'admins.approve',
    ]);
});
```

**AdminController:**

```php
public function show()
{
    return Datatables::of(User::query()->whereNotNull('email_verified_at'))->make(true);
}

public function approve(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->approved_by = Auth::user()->name;
    $user->approved_at = new \DateTime();

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/admins/show');
}
```

**Datatable function:**

```js
$(function () {
    $('#admins').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        scrollX: true,
        order: [[1, "asc"]],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        ajax: '{{ url('admins/ show') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'email_verified_at', name: 'email_verified_at' },
            { data: 'approved_by', name: 'approved_by' }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                targets: 5,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (row.approved_by === null) {
                        return "<form action=\"/admins/approve/" + row.id + "\" method=\"put\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value=\"Approve\"></form><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</button>";
                    } else {
                        return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Reject</button><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</button>";
                    }
                },
                className: "col-action",
                searchable: false,
                orderable: false
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP verbs like **PUT** are generally not supported by the webservers, Laravel achieves this using method spoofing, so you'll need to pass an input type=hidden specifying the method you want to use. And your form action needs to "POST" for the same reason.

```
 return "<form action=\"/admins/approve/" + row.id + "\" method=\"POST\">
               <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_method\" value=\"PUT\">"
```

Also make sure you are passing the **csrf-token** with your POST requests.

`<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"{{ csrf_token() }}\">"`

Comment: I've tried POST method, but got "419:Page Expired" error.

Comment: you are not passing the csrf token with your post request

Comment: i updated my answer, with csrf_token input field, add it your existing fields.

Comment: you have misspelled `csrf_token()`

Answer (score 0):

1. In laravel, you need to send a key `_method` with value `PUT`(case insensitive) to be able to tell laravel that you are sending request with `put` method.
   [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing)
2. Since your route is in `web.php` and your method is not `GET`, you need to send a csrf token with the request. Send a key `_token` with value of csrf token. You can do this by default for all the `$.ajax` requests. Use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) code.

Make these changes in your render method and you will be good to go.

```
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
  if (row.approved_by === null) {
    return "<form action=\"/admins/approve/" + row.id + "\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_method\" value=\"PUT\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value=\"Approve\"></form><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</button>";
  } else {
    return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Reject</button><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</button>";
  }
},
```

I have not included code to send csrf token. You can do it for the whole application using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) link.